# Validating fields of a type before applying a custom constraint validator to it

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, bean-validation

I have a class that is something like this

```
@MyValidator
class Demo {
    @NotNull
    Instant startDate
    ...
}
```

In the ConstraintValidator for the MyValidator constraint, I make a call that requires startDate not to be null.

I wouldn't have to worry about that if the @NotNull constraint on startDate is validated before my @MyValidator constraint is, but in my tests @MyValidator is validated first and I am getting an NPE.

How can I either indicate to the validator that calls my ConstraintValidator that the @MyValidator constraint should be validated after the field level @NotNull constraint is, or explicitly validate the @NotNull constraint myself as the first step in my ConstraintValidator implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control validation order by using validation groups and group sequences.
Info: Group sequence stops validation if one of the groups, defined in a group sequence, fails.

http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence

If you are using Hibernate Validator, this link may help too:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html